Trying to figure why the Fortran "G" format outputs asterisks
The following outputs asterisks (when I would expect -10.00) and I'm trying to figure out why:
WRITE(*,'(G10.4)') -9.99961061241612  
WRITE(*,'(G10.4)') -9.9996

I've tried the following cases:
WRITE(*,'(G10.4)') -9.99961061241612  Outputs: **********
WRITE(*,'(G10.4)') -9.99999999999999  Outputs: -10.00
WRITE(*,'(G10.4)') -9.999             Outputs: -9.999
WRITE(*,'(G10.4)') -9.9999            Outputs: **********
WRITE(*,'(G10.4)') -9.99999           Outputs: -10.00
WRITE(*,'(G10.4)')  9.9999            Outputs: 10.000

It seems to outputs asterisks when it as to round up on the 4th decimal on negative numbers.
Can someone explains why and how I can account for this behavior ?
from what I could gather, The G format should work the following way :
If the value is greater than 0.1 but not too large to fit in the field, then the number is written as if in decimal format (similar to the F descriptor) using a field width of w and outputting d significant digits. This number is followed by four blanks. Otherwise, it behaves exactly like the Ew.d descriptor.
Where:
w   total field width (must be greater than zero)
d   number of digits to the right of the decimal point (may be zero)
for example:
WRITE(*,'(G10.4)') -0.000099961061241612 Outputs: -.9996E-04
I'm using Intel Fortran Compiler   Package ID: w_oneAPI_2022.0.0.161 with Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.40

I would expect the output to be -10.00

The current Intel compiler also gives remark #8291: Recommended relationship between field width 'W' and the number of fractional digits 'D' in this edit descriptor is 'W>=D+7'., When it does not fit it wants to print -10.000.

It works fine with the gfortran compiler. -10.000 would be five significant digits, not four.

If you do write(*,"(g11.4)") -9.9999 (note the 11, not 10, so plenty of room) the NAG and gfortran compilers correctly give -10.00 and the ifx (and ifort) compilers incorrectly give -10.000 (too many sig figs). The same problem arises with +9.9999.

@lastchance thanks that explains it. The project I'm working on was switched to ifort

@Phosphoenix : actually I think that the Intel compilers are wrong here, so it's a good question.

The asterisks appear because the G10.4 format can't fit the rounded result of -9.99961061241612 within the 10-character field after rounding to -10.00. This happens when rounding up a negative number exceeds the field width.
Solutions:

Increase the field width, e.g., G12.4, to allow more space:
WRITE(*,'(G12.4)') -9.99961061241612


Alternatively, use the F format for fixed-point output:
WRITE(*,'(F10.4)') -9.99961061241612




how do you explain WRITE(,'(G10.4)') -9.9999 not working but  WRITE(,'(G10.4)') -9.99999 working ? both fit within 10 characters.

@Phosphoenix You must not forget that a part of those 10 characters would be used for the exponent. You only have 6 characters and -10.000 is 7 characters.
